# С помощью чего в форме QWidget можно нарисовать шахматное поле?

Tags: qt, pyqt5, разработка-игр, графика, qwidget

Использовала `QGraphicsScene`, но не очень удобно, т.к. не знаю тогда значения квадратиков, в соответствии с которыми  потом буду расставлять фигурки на поле.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Square(QtWidgets.QGraphicsWidget):
    def __init__(self, color):
        super().__init__()

        self.resize(640, 640) 
        self.setMinimumSize(80, 80)

        if color:
            self.color = QtCore.Qt.white
        else:
            self.color = QtCore.Qt.black 

    def paint(self, qp, option, widget):
        qp.fillRect(option.rect, self.color)   


class Scene(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.container = QtWidgets.QGraphicsWidget()
        layout = QtWidgets.QGraphicsGridLayout(self.container)
        layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.container.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.addItem(self.container)
        for row in range(8):
            for column in range(8):
                square = Square(not (row + column) & 1)
                layout.addItem(square, row, column, 1, 1)


class Chess(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(640, 640) 

        scene = Scene()
        self.setScene(scene)
        self.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setFrameShape(0)
        # make it transparent
        self.setStyleSheet('QGraphicsView {background: transparent;}')

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        self.fitInView(self.scene().container, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Chess()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]